# libGDX get pixel color from sprite or texture

Tags: android, libgdx

I was searching it on net but i wasn't able to find any solution. I have a sprite or a texture and when i touch it i want to get pixel color from touch coordinates.

so I have:

```
 if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            Rectangle spriteBounds = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
            if (sprite.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
                //and here something like
                //Color color = sprite.getPixelColor(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
            }
        }
```

Is it possible? Thank you :)

Comment: I looked at the question but there is nothing about libgdx library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following might work, but is untested. You can get the color via the `Pixmap` of the sprite's `Texture`. You need to make sure that you are converting the input (screen) coordinates properly to the local coordinates of the texture.

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
    Rectangle spriteBounds = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    if (spriteBounds.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
        Texture texture = sprite.getTexture();

        int spriteLocalX = (int) (Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getX());
        // we need to "invert" Y, because the screen coordinate origin is top-left
        int spriteLocalY = (int) ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) - sprite.getY());

        int textureLocalX = sprite.getRegionX() + spriteLocalX;
        int textureLocalY = sprite.getRegionY() + spriteLocalY;

        if (!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
            texture.getTextureData().prepare();
        }
        Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
        return new Color(pixmap.getPixel(textureLocalX, textureLocalY));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why is that so, but I had to negate second if because sprite is drawing 0, 0 left bottom corner but input is 0, 0 in left upper corner.

Comment: @miskohut Libgdx takes input in its native coordinates, which happens to differ from the rendering coordinates. To fix this you can either subtract the height from the y coordinate or call `camera.unproject(Vector3 coords)`