# How to get and set pixels in textures (LibGDX)

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, textures, pixel

I'm making a game where I have 2+ teams, and - as I don't want to draw every possible coloured building - I'm looking for a way to substitute a certain colour in a texture to the team's colour. Is there a way to set and pixel colours in LibGDX so I can do this? By the way, my texture is a Texture, not a TextureRegion or anything else.

Comment: Use shaders to tint the texture colors. If you make the texture grayscale, then multiplying the texture value by the color (ex. `(1,0,0,1)` for red) will color it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The problem with that would be that I don't want the whole image to be recoloured, just certain colours in it - for example changing all orange to, say, blue.

Comment: Then use multiple textures; one for the colorable parts, one for the parts that stay the same, and blend them together in your shader.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that then! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the pixel data from a texture, [illustrated in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28405361/2974766).

You could then create a new `PixMap`, and draw to it pixel by pixel from the original `PixMap` - replacing whatever designated color with your team color.

There's probably ways to optimize this, because it's going to be very expensive, which even the LibGDX API points out somewhere (*but couldn't find it, offhand*) - off the top of my head you could probably draw large squares of the same color at the same time. if you had a good algorithm for finding the squares.

Check API for [`PixMap`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html) for working with it. You can get the new texture by doing `Texture newTex = new Texture(PixMap);`

---

### However

It's very possible, as @ColonelThirtyTwo suggests in his comment, that blending images will save on a lot of processing time. It is much easier to create the original image in gray-scale and then blend the image. This will work especially well if the entire image will be varying shades of the team color.

But, lets say you want a specific color for everything except the flag on a building. You *could* make the flag a separate image and just color that one image the same you would with the entire image, same way as [@Xoppa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33745322/2974766) suggests. (*Since I see his answer says the same as I write this ;)* ) And that is the approach I would take if it were me.

Otherwise, you'd create two images. The original image, and your mask (which designates where the team color pixels will be applied). You'd multiply the mask with your desired color, and then you'd apply the mask to your original image, which has gray-scale values on the pixels where the mask will be applied.

I, myself, would either blend the entire image with the color, or if you didn't want the whole image multiplied by the color, split the image into two images and just blend the one that should be blended.

Comment: I'll try the PixMap idea. It shouldn't be too slow, as I would only change the colours every time I make a new castle (Not very often). Do you know of a way to create a pixmap from a texture?

Comment: @ZacG Only from what I've read in the link I provided in the first paragraph. The primary line seems to be `Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();` - I haven't had to do it myself so not sure how well it works or if there are any conditions to be aware of when using it.

Comment: @ZacG If you find low frame-rates in the future, first thing you should try is using your generic Texture instead of the team-colored one and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the texture data (which involves copying it from VRAM to RAM and back) or modify it before uploading to GPU (directly modifying the Pixmap). But you probably don't have to do that. Instead you could do that using tinting as Colonel Thirty Two mentioned. Luckily SpriteBatch has this functionality built-in. You can use the batch.setColor method for it. If you are using scene2d then you can use actor.setColor.

```
batch.setColor(Color.RED); // Everything after this will be tinted (multiplied with) red
batch.draw(texture, x, y);
batch.setColor(Color.WHITE); // set it back to white for the remaining draw calls
```

If you only need to change the color of part of the image. Then split the image into two parts. For which, btw, I would strongly encourage to use a TextureAtlas, but that's not related to your question.

Comment: Ill try that - it seems as though it should work. :)