# Limit touch area to Texture area in libgdx

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I load textures and convert them to sprites. The image below shows how typical sprite looks like. The shapes varies from sprites to sprite. I wont to move these sprites when user touches just the surface area. Currently I am using rectangle bounds to detect if user touched it or not. This approach is not clean becuase the texture is not a rectangle. As a consequence users can drag it without precisely touching it. The question is how to create a touch area just to represent the texture area (that is non-transparent pixel area or exclude gray color area in the image below).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this with color picking. By first determining which pixel on the sprite is touched and then check if the touched pixel is transparent. With code taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405361/libgdx-get-pixel-color-from-sprite-or-texture) and altered a bit (not tested):

```
Color pickedColor = null;
Rectangle spriteBounds = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
if (spriteBounds.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())) {
    Texture texture = sprite.getTexture();

    int spriteLocalX = (int) (Gdx.input.getX() - sprite.getX());
    // we need to "invert" Y, because the screen coordinate origin is top-left
    int spriteLocalY = (int) ((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY()) - sprite.getY());

    int textureLocalX = sprite.getRegionX() + spriteLocalX;
    int textureLocalY = sprite.getRegionY() + spriteLocalY;

    if (!texture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
        texture.getTextureData().prepare();
    }
    Pixmap pixmap = texture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
    pickedColor = new Color(pixmap.getPixel(textureLocalX, textureLocalY));
}

//Check for transparency
if (pickedColor != null && pickedColor.a != 0) {
    //The picked pixel is not transparent, the nontransparent texture shape was touched
}
```

Have in mind this hasn't been tested and can probably be optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Cant we create a polygon to represent the area? This looks expensive if I have close to 200 spites.

Comment: As far as I know there's no simple way to create a polygon from a texture area, your texture is still rectangular and you would still have to check which pixels are transparent and not to create the polygon and the final shape will be complex due to the curves. Remember that the pixelcolor is only calculated if you actually touch the sprite rectangle (first if statement) and you can terminate as soon as one sprite is hit (the topmost puzzle piece). So I'd be surprised if there are cases where the calculations are done for more than 5 sprites.

Comment: One way to optimize it would be to save all the pixmaps beforehand (connected with some sort of name/id to the sprite) to not recreate the pixmaps every time. Calculating the localX and localY can't be avoided since you can move the sprites.

Comment: One other option, if you have a fixed set of shapes (lets say 10 different shapes) for your pieces you can always manually create your polygons for each shape, then create an invisible modelinstance/actor for each peice, move it with the piece and do the picking on that modelinstance/actor.

Comment: Thanks. I have android android.graphics.Path objects representing the piece, is there away to use that instead in libgdx? Or convert android.graphics.Path to a polygon somehow.

Comment: I don't know really, but from a quick look at the Path documentation you may be able to use the approximate method to appriximate the path to line segments and get the x and y coordinates in a float array, and from these coordinates create the models in libgdx. I believe that would require a lot more work than the above approach, so I'd suggest trying the above first and see if there's actually any performance problems which I doubt there will be. Remember you only need to do the calculations on touchDown (not drag or touchup) and only on the sprites who's rectangles are hit.